# How to split the ending of a file name using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, split

How can I split the ending of a file, like for instance I want file01 instead of file01.xlsx

My written code:

`var filename = $v('P40_UPLOAD').split('\\').pop().split('/').pop();`

```
var s = $s("P40_NAME",filename);
```

`s.split('.')[0];`

Unfortunately it doens't work.

Comment: If dot is the separator in the filename, then why are you splitting on space?

Answer (score 0):

If you know the length of the extension, you can use x.slice(0, -4) (where 4 is the three characters of the extension and the dot).

Comment: is there any reason why it doesn't work with oracle (apex)?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```js
var file = "file01.xlsx";

var index = file.lastIndexOf(".");
 var filename = file.substring(0,index);
 console.log(filename);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this Regex:

```js
var url = 'http://stackoverflow.com/file01.xlsx';
var filename = url.match( /([^\/]+)(?=\.\w+$)/ )[0];
console.log( filename )
```

Alternately, you can do this without regular expressions altogether, by finding the position of the last `/` and the last `.` using `lastIndexOf` and getting a `substring` between those points:

```js
var url = 'http://stackoverflow.com/file01.xlsx';
var filename = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf( '/' ) + 1, url.lastIndexOf( '.' ));
console.log( filename )
```